# Optimizing paging between ImageViews in Android?

Tags: android, optimization, drawable

For the application I'm currently working on, I created something like `ImageSwitcher` for multiple images (imagine iPhone's `UIScrollView` with paging enabled).

At first, I hard coded some `ImageViews` and loaded their drawable resources on creation/inflation, but after some tweaks (and what I thought were improvements), I reduced the needed views to 3, of which 2 are `ImageViews` used for displaying of the current page and animating between current and new page.

With this change, I began to use `setImageResource`/`setImageDrawable` for the dynamic loading of the new image in my 2 `ImageViews` before sliding through pages (I am using PNG files, sized for HVGA displays).

To my disappointment, the performance got worse, to the extent of feeling some lag when sliding faster through the pages.
A quick look in `TraceView` revealed that 17.4% of total time while using the app, over 5 times more than the next heavy method, was consumed from `BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset`, called by my dynamic setting of drawable resource.

I'm thinking of ways to circumvent this, and I want to do it in the best way possible, so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It sounds like you've reinvented ImageSwitcher. ImageSwitcher does just that: 2 ImageViews used for displaying the current image and the next image. Unlike what it might sound like, it's not just used for switching back and forth between the _same_ two images, as it might initially seem. I often use it for such things as animating through a whole feed of images (and use another switcher to also animate the titles in and out). I don't know that this will solve your performance issues, but at least it could factor out some things.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

I had to reinvent ImageSwitcher for several reasons - first, because I started with it containing multiple ImageViews, and then reduced them to current view and helper view, second, because I wanted to have control over another, TextView component, which should be easily reachable from the ImageViews - I thought I'll flatten the hierarchy and use my custom switcher view, which will do only what I want it to do.

In the end, after playing with AllocationTracker and TraceView, I don't think the problem is in the custom ViewGroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In which format do you have the images?

Android works natively with RGB565 images, so if you can convert your images to that format, decoding will be much faster.

Comment: Hello, I've mentioned that I get the images in PNG format, but I don't know if the buffer for these files is RGB 565 (that's 16-bit Highcolor, right?).

I tried to load bitmap directly from image converted to .rgb565, but Android's BitmapFactory doesn't seem to work with it.

Anyway, thanks for the idea.